# Cookies visible from URL bar but not visible in the Application tab of browser developer tool

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-devtools, httponly

If you go to [didthanoskill.me](http://www.didthanoskill.me/) and try to access cookies from the URL bar, you can clearly see "**1 Cookie in use**". On `document.cookie` in the console, empty string is returned. I thought the cookies must be **HttpOnly** so I headover to Application tab in browser dev tool and there also no cookies are showing. Weird!

Any idea why is so happening?

Comment: When you’re creating your cookie, you’re setting the expire date to expires=Sat, 27 Apr 2019 00:00:00 UTC. Why are you using an already past date (which is how you delete a cookie)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than hard coding the cookie’s expire date to 27 Apr 2019 (which is a past date and how a cookie is deleted), you could use new Date and add some number of days for how long the status should last (I used 7 for my example).

```
function onLoad() {
    var displayElement = document.getElementById("display");
    var resultDate;
    var randomNumber = getCookie("thanosNumber");
    
    if (!randomNumber) {
        resultDate = new Date();
        resultDate.setDate(resultDate.getDate()+7);
        randomNumber = Math.random();
        document.cookie = "thanosNumber=" + randomNumber + ";expires="+resultDate.toGMTString();
    } else {
        randomNumber = Number(randomNumber);
    }
    
    if (randomNumber < 0.5) {
        displayElement.textContent = "You were slain by Thanos, for the good of the Universe.";
    } else {
        displayElement.textContent = "You were spared by Thanos.";
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not creating any cookies. I am trying to access the cookies which is set by the website didthanoskill.me. you probably wanna reread the question again.

Comment: Whomever is setting the cookie is setting the expire date to 2019 (expires=Sat, 27 Apr 2019 00:00:00 UTC). That’s telling the browser the cookie has been deleted. Chrome will still show the cookie when viewed through site information in the address bar, but in Developer Tools, there is no cookie (as it’s considered deleted). The cookie is being deleted as soon as it’s created, so that’s why you can’t see it. Firefox shows no cookie information for the page.

Comment: Hmm possible! looking at the cookies there is `thanosNumber` which seems like on value `>0.5` give "thanos spared" and on `<0.5` gives "thanos killed" but what I am thinking is, if the cookie is expired then how is the website accessing it and why? Anyways it's out of context to the question. Also notice no cookies being transferred along with the request.